# General thing regarding Apache Ant introduction

Tags: java, ant

From the Apache Ant introduction it is said that

> Why another build tool when there is already make, gnumake, nmake, jam, and others? Because all those tools have limitations that Ant's original author couldn't live with when developing software across multiple platforms. Make-like tools are inherently shell-based: they evaluate a set of dependencies, then execute commands not unlike what you would issue on a shell. This means that you can easily extend these tools by using or writing any program for the OS that you are working on; however, this also means that you limit yourself to the OS, or at least the OS type, such as Unix, that you are working on.

I don't understand this statement:

> "This means that you can easily extend these tools by using or writing any program for the OS that you are working on"

And

> "Granted, this removes some of the expressive power that is inherent in being able to construct a shell command such as `find . -name foo -exec rm {}`,"

If someone could help me understand this please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As an example, suppose I'm developing for unix, and I need to [rot13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) a file full of secrets as part of my build process. In `make` the rule would be something like this:

```
kfc-spices.rot13.txt: kfc-spices.txt
    tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' < kfc-spices.txt > kfc-spices.rot13.txt
```

With a mere two lines of text, I've easily extended my build system with the ability to rot13 files by using a program provided by my OS. On the other hand, my build process will utterly fail on systems that don't provide a program named `tr` which acts like the unix `tr`.

[The "granted" line](https://ant.apache.org/manual/intro.html) refers to the fact that `ant` is extended by writing java classes rather than through running OS commands. So to portably rot13 a file in ant, you'd have to [write a custom task in java](http://www.developer.com/lang/article.php/10924_3636196_2/More-on-Custom-Ant-Tasks.htm). This is more work, and may end up being less flexible. The `make` example could be trivially altered to do [double Rot13](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090312090137AANbXEf). But it might be difficult to use the ant task in ways the original developer didn't envision.